# mysql storing data in multiple tables or combine?

Tags: php, mysql

Im making an application where users are able to comment on a lot of things, like blog posts, uploaded songs, pictures and so on.

Is it better to store ALL comments in **one** table where you have a column that points to what the comment was posted, e.g. blog, picture etc.

Or is it better to store them in **separate** tables, like "**blogcomments**" table, "**picturecomments**" table etc? Say for a site with 10000 plus users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all comments have the same data being stored (e.g. comment content, user who posted the comment, etc), then it would make the post sense to keep them all in a single table. If they have different formats, then put them in separate tables.

Comment: Yes they all have the same format. Like 'comment','userid','ownerid' and so on. Ok Ill go for the first sollution then, and store them all in a single table. Thanks for the quick answer :) Appreciated!

Comment: One more question. What is the best approach to doing this then? Hidden input field with for example "type"? Or maybe check to see what page the user is on and add the appropriate type for that?

Comment: @George I think is add a column "type" and have a ref id to another table. The table can be like comment_type(Id, Name) where Name is Photo, Video, Blog and so on.

Comment: Yes thats a good idea to save some space :) But how do i pass that information on from say the blog, when a user makes a comment? How to see where a user left the comment? where does the ref id, from your example, come from?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the first approach is the better one. Infact, this way, you can add (or remove) type(s) of comment (I mean post comment, blog comment and so on) without adding or deleting every time a table. I think this it is a more scalable solution.